Create a CheckBox with appearance of Button
I am trying to create a Checkbox with appearance of button. When i set he content of ToggleButton it changes the Checkbox text, but when i change IsChecked it is not getting updated in checkbox. How to implement it. It is Ok to use Button instead but i need to define a Dependency property(Which i have no idea how to update IsChecked of checkbox in setter) the since Button does not have IsChecked.

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <ToggleButton Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content}">
            <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=IsChecked}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ControlTemplate>
 
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource CheckButtonTemplate}" Content="Test" IsChecked="True"/>

</Grid>


What exactly distinguishes "a Checkbox with appearance of button" from a ToggleButton?

You don't wrap a button into a button. This only introduces issues like the one you are having now. Just override the ControlTemplate to change the appearance. To replicate your current attempt, you would have to use a ToggleButton and then add a ContentPresenter  for the content (e.g. text) and a check mark (e.g. a Unicode character for checked and unchecked mark hosted in a TextBlock) to the ControlTemplate. Then toggle that check mark using a Trigger that triggers on ToggleButton.IsChecked

i have added screenshot. It looks like  Checkbox placed on a button or a rounded rectangle. It has to be a template because i need to reuse it with different title

Considering your request to have a "button" with a checkbox inside of it, instead of making a custom style of a checkbox, you could create a ToggleButton with a CheckBox within it to include the visuals, and bind the CheckBox's IsChecked to the parent.
Here's an example of a XAML block to achieve that.
<ToggleButton>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="My Toggle Option"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
       </StackPanel>
 </ToggleButton>

Alternatively, you can use just a Toggle Button for this functionality, unless you require this specific design (of a check box).
